# MySQL Insert Into w/ Select Query containing CASE WHEN

Tags: mysql, insert, case

I have an INSERT INTO trigger that I would like the SELECT part to evaluate a field's value (RDO)and return a value to SchedStatus according to the "days off" value of RDO compared to the DAYNAME of the date assigned to the parent schedule. The schedule itself is created in a while loop of a php document (which works well). Below are my two attempts at evaluating the RDO value:

```
INSERT INTO sched_personnel (Sched_Shift_ID, UnitNumber, SupervisorNumber, Rank, Lunch, Assignment, Shift, Squad, RDOs, SchedStatus)  
      SELECT NEW.Sched_Shift_ID, UnitNumber, SupervisorNumber, Rank, Lunch, Assignment, Shift, Squad, RDO, @SchedStatus
      CASE
        WHEN RDO = 'SAT/SUN' AND (DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) = 'Saturday' OR DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) ='Sunday') THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN RDO = 'SUN/MON' AND (DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) = 'Sunday' OR DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) ='Monday') THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN RDO = 'MON/TUE' AND (DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) = 'Monday' OR DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) ='Tuesday') THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN RDO = 'TUE/WED' AND (DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) = 'Tuesday' OR DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) ='Wednesday') THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN RDO = 'WED/THU' AND (DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) = 'Wednesday' OR DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) ='Thursday') THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN RDO = 'THU/FRI' AND (DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) = 'Thursday' OR DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) ='Friday') THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN RDO = 'FRI/SAT' AND (DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) = 'Friday' OR DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) ='Saturday') THEN 'OFF'
        ELSE 'ONS'
      END AS @SchedStatus
      FROM accounts 
      WHERE accounts.Shift = NEW.Shift AND accounts.AccountStatus = 'Active';
```

I also tried:

```
INSERT INTO sched_personnel (Sched_Shift_ID, UnitNumber, SupervisorNumber, Rank, Lunch, Assignment, Shift, Squad, RDOs, SchedStatus)  
      SELECT NEW.Sched_Shift_ID, UnitNumber, SupervisorNumber, Rank, Lunch, Assignment, Shift, Squad, RDO, @SchedStatus
      CASE
        WHEN RDO = 'SAT/SUN' AND DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN RDO = 'SUN/MON' AND DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) IN ('Sunday', 'Monday') THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN RDO = 'MON/TUE' AND DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday') THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN RDO = 'TUE/WED' AND DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) IN ('Tuesday', 'Wednesday') THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN RDO = 'WED/THU' AND DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) IN ('Wednesday', 'Thursday') THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN RDO = 'THU/FRI' AND DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) IN ('Thursday', 'Friday') THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN RDO = 'FRI/SAT' AND DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) IN ('Friday', 'Saturday') THEN 'OFF'
        ELSE 'ONS'
      END AS @SchedStatus
      FROM accounts 
      WHERE accounts.Shift = NEW.Shift AND accounts.AccountStatus = 'Active';
```

I receive an error:

SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN RDO = 'SAT/SUN' AND DAY NAME(NEW.Shift Date) IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') at line 4 .

If I eliminate the CASE portion of the query the child records are added to each parent record created with out error. The end state desired is a each child record (sched_perssonel) inserted having a 'SchedStatus' that correspnds to the default RDO of the individual hence the CASE evaluating the RDO compared to the date of the Schedule (tabel sched_shift). I can't get the CASE WHEN THEN correct.

Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: what's your problem  .. you have error? show  error message ....wrong result  ...update your question and add  a clear data sample the expected result and your actual result

Comment: I've added the error to the question and the desired result. I use HeidiSQL to interface with the MySQL database and construct the TRIGGER. The code is validated when saving the TRIGGER and the above error is the result. Thank you.

Comment: i have posted  an answer  hope is useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found 3 error

1 ) In your code  you have 10 column for into but 11  in select ..

2 ) In your code you have

```
  ...,   @SchedStatus

  CASE
    WHEN RDO = 'SAT/SUN' .......
```

You missed  a comma  between @SchedStatus and CASE
    But looking to you code  ..  i think you dont need  @schedStatus and i have removed

3)  you have an alias @schedStatus at  the end of CASE ...but using insert select don't need alias

```
INSERT INTO sched_personnel (Sched_Shift_ID, UnitNumber, SupervisorNumber, Rank, Lunch, Assignment, Shift, Squad, RDOs, SchedStatus)  
    SELECT NEW.Sched_Shift_ID
      , UnitNumber
      , SupervisorNumber
      , Rank
      , Lunch
      , Assignment
      , Shift
      , Squad
      , RDO
      , CASE
      WHEN RDO = 'SAT/SUN' AND (DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) = 'Saturday' OR DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) ='Sunday') THEN 'OFF'
      WHEN RDO = 'SUN/MON' AND (DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) = 'Sunday' OR DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) ='Monday') THEN 'OFF'
      WHEN RDO = 'MON/TUE' AND (DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) = 'Monday' OR DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) ='Tuesday') THEN 'OFF'
      WHEN RDO = 'TUE/WED' AND (DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) = 'Tuesday' OR DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) ='Wednesday') THEN 'OFF'
      WHEN RDO = 'WED/THU' AND (DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) = 'Wednesday' OR DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) ='Thursday') THEN 'OFF'
      WHEN RDO = 'THU/FRI' AND (DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) = 'Thursday' OR DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) ='Friday') THEN 'OFF'
      WHEN RDO = 'FRI/SAT' AND (DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) = 'Friday' OR DAYNAME(NEW.ShiftDate) ='Saturday') THEN 'OFF'
      ELSE 'ONS'
    END A
    FROM accounts 
    WHERE accounts.Shift = NEW.Shift AND accounts.AccountStatus = 'Active';
```

Comment: The code validates. Thank you. The 'Case When' works perfectly.